# Can't get my head around the problem, list index out of range (inside 3 loops)

Tags: python

I know `list index out of range` has been covered a million times before and I know the issue is probably that I am trying to reference an index position that does not exist but as there are 3 for loops nested I just cant figure out what is going on.

I am trying to calculate the frequency of each letter of the alphabet in a list of words.

```
alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
g = list(alphabet_string)
a_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y = 0

for word in words:
    for chars in word:
        for letters in chars:
            if letters == g[y]:
                a_count[y] = a_count[y] +1
        y = y + 1
print(a_count[0])
```

`word` is in the format of: ['ZYMIC']

`chars` is in the format of: ZYMIC

`letters` is in the format of: C

If I substitute the y value for a value between 0 and 25 then it returns as expected.
I have a feeling the issue is as stated above that I am exceeding the index number of 25, so I guess `y = y + 1` is in the wrong position. I have however tried it in different positions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks everyone so much, never had this many responses before, all very helpful!

Comment: You should loop through the alphabet letters as the *outer loop*.

Comment: There are a lot of other improvements that can be made, but that's for another time/question/stackexchange site.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will be tremendously helpful here, reducing all your code to basically one line.

Comment: But do sort the problem with your own code first, as a good learning experience. Otherwise you'll just be using a random black box you grabbed from the internet.

Comment: From what I understand, y is being increased (#words * #their_charts) times. I don't know how many charts there are but surely is the number of charts is more than len(a_count) then there would be a problem. I think maybe you have to do the increasing under the if statement. But you should decide that based on your goal

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, as you can tell I am very new to Python, going to try each of the solutions e.g. collections.counter, dictionary key pairs etc. then dish out upvotes etc.! Will let you know how I get on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing `a_count` as a dictionary is the better option for this problem.

```
a_count = {}
for word in words:
    for chars in word:
        for letters in chars:
            a_count[letters] = a_count.get(letters, 0) + 1
```

You can also use the `Counter()` class from the `collections` library.

```
from collections import Counter

a_count = Counter()
for word in words:
    for chars in word:
        for letters in chars:
            a_count[letters] += 1

print(a.most_common())
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution via `Counter` -

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['TEST','ZYMIC']
print(Counter(''.join(words)))
```

If you wanna stick to your code then change the `if condition` -

when `y` = 0 `g[y]` means 'A' and you're checking if `'A' == 'Z'` which is the 1st letter. Basically, you need to fetch the index location of the element from list g and increase the value by `1`. That's what you need to do to make it work. If I understood your problem correctly.

```
import string
words = ['ZYMIC']
alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
g = list(alphabet_string)
a_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for word in words:
    for chars in word:
        for letters in chars:
            if letters in g:
                y = g.index(letters)
                a_count[y] += 1
print(a_count)
```

And you can very well replace the `if condition`, and check for the index directly because the letter will always be there in g. Therefore, this particular condition is redundant here.

```
for word in words:
    for chars in word:
        for letters in chars:
            y = g.index(letters)
            a_count[y] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of list a_count.
I would suggest another approach here, based on dictionaries:

```
listeletters = ['foihroh','ZYMIC','ajnaisui', 'fjindsonosn']

alphabeth = {'a' : 0, 
        'b' : 0,
        'c': 0}

for string in listeletters:
    for l in string:
        if l in alphabeth.keys():
            alphabeth[l] = alphabeth[l] + 1

print(alphabeth)
```

I inialize the alphabeth and then I get the result wanted